# Iterated Sums of Differences

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

I recently came across the sum $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (e- S_n) = e,$$ where $S_n = 1+1+1/2+1/6+...+1/n!$ is the classic $n$th partial sum of $e.$ This gave me an idea. Let $a_{0,0}, a_{0,1}, a_{0,2},\dots$ be a convergent sequence, let $$S_{m,n}=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_{m,k}$$

$$a_{i+1,j} = S_{i,j+1}$$

Now let $b_n=S_{n,0}.$ For the sequence $a_{0,n}=1/n!,$ we have $b_0=e,$ and as I mentioned earlier, $b_1=e.$ I think that $1<b_2<2,$ as the sum decays quickly after the initial term. Also interesting is the fact that if you take $a_{0,n}=0.5^n,$ then $b_{n}=2 \, \forall n,$ as $a_{i,j}=a_{0,j}=2^{-j} \, \forall i,j.$ Perhaps this is the only such sequence with the property that $\{b_n\}$ is constant.

Is there any merit to such sequences? I would like to know if it is possible to determine the long term behavior of $b_n$ for various sequences $\{a_{0,n}\}.$ I believe that someone has already thought of this before, and done extensive research on it, as such an idea seems too simple to have been overlooked.

Comment: Looks wrong. Should be infinity.

Comment: Perhaps an example is better. Consider the sequence 1,1/2,1/4,1/8...; it has sum 2, so form the next series 2-1, 2-(1+1/2), 2-(1+1/2+1/4),... which is identical to the original series and thus also has sum 2. This repeats ad infinitum, explaining why b_n=2 for all n in this case. Now for my other example, consider the sequence 1,1,1/2,1/6,1/24...; it has sum $e,$ so we form the series $e-1, e-(1+1), e-(1+1+1/2),...$ which remarkably also has sum $e.$ Now the next series is $e-(e-1)=1, e-(e-1+e-2)=3-e, e-(e-1+e-2+e-2.5)=5.5-2e,...$ which seems to have $1<S<2;$ I haven't found an exact value.